# How to integrate Bootstrap input-group in Ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, input

I'm trying to integrate Ruby on Rails to a Bootstrap input. It works but the Bootstrap style is lost... ? Any idea ? Thanks !

```
<div id="create-input" style="display: none">
  <div id="choose-report" class="input-group input-group-sm">
        <%= form_for @report do |form| %>
            <span class="input-group-addon">Report</span>
        <%= form.text_field :title, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Type here the name of your new report..." %>
        <% end %>
    </div>          
</div>
```

Comment: A screenshot is often helpful (you can edit your question).  Post a link to a screenshot if you have trouble uploading.

Comment: I would check to see if your styles are showing up in your rendered code or not.  Either you are misusing the Rails helpers (and the Bootstrap classes will not be in your HTML) or you are not properly loading Bootstrap.